# The identifier id is missing for a query of PrManagerBundle\Entity\eb_user

Tags: php, angular, symfony, doctrine

i'm trying to delete an object by the id from my database using 
`<button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="removeUser()"> Delete</button></td>` in the frontend but the link does not work. I get an error:

```
The identifier id is missing for a query of PrManagerBundle\Entity\eb_user.
```

here is my entity:

```
namespace PrManagerBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * eb_user
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="eb_user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PrManagerBundle\Repository\eb_userRepository")
 */
class eb_user
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $nom;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="prenom", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $prenom;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="tel", type="string", nullable = true)
 */
private $tel;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mail", type="string", length=255, nullable = true)
 */
private $mail;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="domaine", type="string", length=255, nullable = true)
 */
private $domaine;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PrManagerBundle\Entity\eb_role", inversedBy="eb_user")
 */
private $x_eb_role;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set nom
 *
 * @param string $nom
 *
 * @return eb_user
 */
public function setNom($nom)
{
    $this->nom = $nom;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get nom
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getNom()
{
    return $this->nom;
}

/**
 * Set prenom
 *
 * @param string $prenom
 *
 * @return eb_user
 */
public function setPrenom($prenom)
{
    $this->prenom = $prenom;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get prenom
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPrenom()
{
    return $this->prenom;
}

/**
 * Set tel
 *
 * @param integer $tel
 *
 * @return eb_user
 */
public function setTel($tel)
{
    $this->tel = $tel;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get tel
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getTel()
{
    return $this->tel;
}

/**
 * Set mail
 *
 * @param string $mail
 *
 * @return eb_user
 */
public function setMail($mail)
{
    $this->mail = $mail;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get mail
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getMail()
{
    return $this->mail;
}

/**
 * Set domaine
 *
 * @param string $domaine
 *
 * @return eb_user
 */
public function setDomaine($domaine)
{
    $this->domaine = $domaine;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get domaine
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getDomaine()
{
    return $this->domaine;
}
/**
 * Set xEbRole
 *
 * @param \PrManagerBundle\Entity\eb_role $xEbRole
 *
 * @return eb_user
 */
public function setXEbRole(\PrManagerBundle\Entity\eb_role $xEbRole = null)
{
    $this->x_eb_role = $xEbRole;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get xEbRole
 *
 * @return \PrManagerBundle\Entity\eb_role
 */
public function getXEbRole()
{
    return $this->x_eb_role;
}
```

}

the controller:

```
public function removeAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $userInfo = json_decode( $request->request->get("user") );
        $eb_user = $em->getRepository('PrManagerBundle:eb_user')->find($request->request->get('id'));
        $em->remove($eb_user);
        $em->flush(); 
        $em->clear();   
        return $this->returnJsonResponse($eb_user);

        /* $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(eb_user::class);
        $editUser = $repository->find($id);
        return $this->returnJsonResponse($editUser);*/
    }
```

and the routing is here:

pr_manager_remove:
    path:     /user/remove/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: PrManagerBundle:User:remove }

Actually the id is not found. I expect the link work correctly

Comment: The controller is not finding the id from your request. Please share the related frontend (html/js) code.

Comment: @SondreEdvardsen here is the component  in which i called the service ``removeUser(id){
    this.createService.removeUser(id)
        .subscribe();
  }``  this is create service.ts ``removeUser(id: number): Observable<{}> {
    return this.http.delete(Statique.DELETE_USER+'/'+id);
  }``

Comment: @SondreEdvardsen this is the ``Statique.DELETE_USER = 'http://localhost/project-manager/backend/web/app_dev.php/user/remove'``  in the backend I configured the route as follows: ``pr_manager_remove:
    path:     /user/remove/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: PrManagerBundle:User:remove }``

Comment: @SondreEdvardsen  and here is the HTML: ``<table class="table table-striped; mat-elevation-z8" style="width: 100%;">
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Nom</th>
    <th>Prénom</th
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor = "let user of users">
    <td>{{user.id}}</td>
    <td>{{user.nom}}</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="removeUser()"> Delete</button></td>
  </tr>``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the userId as a route parameter. That's why it's missing from the request.

The id should be passed as an argument to the the function PrManagerBundle:User:remove.

```
/**
 * @Route("/user/remove/{id}", name="pr_manager_remove")
 */
public function remove($id)
{
    ...
    $eb_user = $em->getRepository('PrManagerBundle:eb_user')->find($id);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I get another error:  ``An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.nom AS nom_2, t0.prenom AS prenom_3, t0.tel AS tel_4, t0.mail AS mail_5, t0.domaine AS domaine_6, t0.x_eb_role_id AS x_eb_role_id_7 FROM eb_user t0 WHERE t0.id = ?' with params ["id"]:

SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERREUR: syntaxe en entrée invalide pour l'entier : « id »``

Comment: Now the param seems to be "id" as a string, not the value of the variable $id. Please double check for typos and share the controller code, if you're still getting errors.

Comment: I modified ``$id`` by ``('id')`` in the controller but nothing has changed. here is the UserController: ``class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function removeAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $eb_user = $em->getRepository('PrManagerBundle:eb_user')->find('id');
        $em->remove($eb_user);
        $em->flush(); 
        $em->clear();   
        return $this->returnJsonResponse($eb_user);
    }
}``

Comment: `->find('id')` should be `->find($id)`